# Angular, header does not refresh after signing in/up

Tags: angular, authentication

as the title says, I want angular to show "Hi, "username"" after a user is logged in or has just signed up. However, my header doesn't seem to receive the information right away, but user has to manually refresh the page for the header to receive it. Below is my "authentication.service"

```
public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any>{
    const base = this.http.post('/user/login', user)
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token){
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        
        return data
        
      })
    )
    return request
  }
  
  public register(user: TokenPayload) : Observable<any>{
    const base = this.http.post('/user/register', user)
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token){
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        return data
      })
    )
    return request
  }
```

signin.component

```
login() {
    this.auth.login(this.credentials).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
  

      },
      err => {
        console.error(err)
      }
    )
  }
```

header.component

```
ngOnInit() {
    if(this.auth.isLoggedIn()){
      this.auth.myProfile().subscribe(user => {
        this.mydetails = user
        console.log(this.mydetails.id)
        
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err)
      })
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check for component communication using RXJS in angular. Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-component-communication-usin-service

Comment: Your header component is only checking for the user logged. You need to use a BehaviourSubject (or a Subject) in your Service and a subscription in your header component to track when a user log in.

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisMinh , I get what you are saying, but I'm not sure how I can use a BehaviourSubject in the login method in my service. Can you give me a more detailed explaination?

Comment: if you google for "angular BehaviourSubject authentication" you will find loads of example. But to summarize. In your AuthenticationService you declare a BehaviourSubject and initialize it with a default value. For example an empty user object.
When a user is login in you just emit the user object with the authentication data with the method next. 
In your header component you subscribe to the BehaviourSubject. When a new value is emitted you just have to test if it's an empty user and do whatever you want.